# Connection between server and client

Tags: java, web-services, http, server, client

In our organization, We have one server in which one folder Log/Response is there. In this folder so many files will be there (XML file). Now I want to write a program to find all XML files which has a *'keyword'* in Java, if possible. And after finding all such file it should return all files name. Here *'keyword'* will be given from client (means user will open one URL/keyword from his browser).

So how can I achieve this thing? Which technology, language and tool I need to use? If I write a program then where exactly I should put it?

Answer (score 1):

You can start from JSP/Servlet as starting point. JSP/Servlet will be communication point between user and server infrastructure where a list of files is located.

To search necessary file: as simple solution you can scan all files in necessary directory. But it will be slow. As more advanced solution, you should use some full text search engine(search will be fast).

Of course, JSP/Servlet will be deployed in servlet container such as Jetty or Tomcat.

That is all :)

Comment: Thanks Oleksandr_DJ for giving more information about 'full text search engine'